# SwiftUI: ForEach within List - What's the advantage?

Tags: swift, swiftui

A have seen this coding-pattern in the code of somebody and played around with it myself.

If I do:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var colors: [Color] = [.red, .blue, .yellow, .pink, .orange, .green]
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(colors, id: \.self) { color in
                Text(color.description)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That works.

Now I change it to:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var colors: [Color] = [.red, .blue, .yellow, .pink, .orange, .green]
    var body: some View {
        List(colors, id: \.self) { color in
            // ForEach(colors, id: \.self) { color in
                Text(color.description)
            // }
        }
    }
}
```

I can't see any difference.

**What's the advantage of having the ForEach within the list?**

**Why not using the list alone?**

Comment: It depends on what you want to do, as you have it there is not a lot of different.
 However, with the `ForEach` you can have `.onDelete{...}` etc...
 when you swipe left, but not with just `List(...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a good question. My understanding:

`List` is similar to `UITableView` or `UICollectionView` with cell-reuse-identifier, hierarchical items etc.

Meanwhile, `ForEach` is a collection of views. Each view's style is rely on `ForEach`'s parent container.

In your first example, you put `ForEach` inside a `List` so that it's applied default `List`'s item style (which is `UITableViewCell` style) to each child view. Then you see it's exactly the same as a `List`.

Let's try to put it inside a `ScrollView` or a `HStack` you will figure it out.

```
ScrollView {
   ForEach(colors, id: \.self) { color in
       Text(color.description)
   }
}
```

```
HStack {
   ForEach(colors, id: \.self) { color in
       Text(color.description)
   }
}
```

Answer to your question:
In most cases you don't need `ForEach` but in some cases, you will need it if your cell has multiple styles.
Take a look at `List` document while creating hierarchical lists, `ForEach` is not needed.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/list